# How to convert UTC time to New York time zone in Microsoft SQl

Tags: sql-server, timezone

How to convert UTC time to New York time zone in Microsoft  SQL

Comment: What version of SQL Server? How is your data stored?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use as following query. For list of time all zone names `select * from sys.time_zone_info`

```
Declare @UTC datetime =  GETUTCDATE();

SELECT @UTC AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time';
```

Also, there are couple of ways which you can [explore here..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)